# Filter nested list based on nested values

Tags: list, flutter, dart, filter

I have the following data structure:

```dart
class FAQCategory {
  late int id;
  late String title;
  late List<FAQItem> items;

  FAQCategory({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.items,
  });
}

class FAQItem {
  late int id;
  late String question;
  late String answer;

  FAQItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.question,
    required this.answer,
  });
}
```

Now I want to filter a `List<FAQCategory>` based on query string but with respect to the fields `title`, `question` and `answer`. If one of the two fields in `FAQItem` match it should include the item, if `title` matches it should include the whole category.

The latter I was able to do with

```dart
_categories
      .where(
        (element) => element.items
            .where((element) => element.question.contains("query"))
            .isNotEmpty,
      )
      .toList();
```

However, I don't have an idea of how to tackle the other condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve it in this way:

```
List<FAQCategory> filtered = [];
for(FAQCategory parent in _categories) {
      final temp = parent.items.where((child) => child.question.contains("query"));
      filtered.add(parent.copyWith(items: temp?.toList()));
}
```

Now you have idea how to do it and you can improve solution if you wish.
Good luck.

Full code copy and paste in dartpad.dev:

```
main() async {
  List<FAQCategory> categories = [
    FAQCategory(id: 1, title: 'Category 1', items: [
      FAQItem(id: 2, answer: 'blabla 2', question: 'query 2.1'),
      FAQItem(id: 3, answer: 'blabla 3', question: 'query 3.1'),
      FAQItem(id: 4, answer: 'blabla 4', question: 'quer 4.1'),
      ]
   ),
  FAQCategory(id: 5, title: 'Category 5', items: [
      FAQItem(id: 6, answer: 'blabla 6', question: 'query 6.1'),
      FAQItem(id: 7, answer: 'blabla 7', question: 'quer 7.1'),
      FAQItem(id: 8, answer: 'blabla 8', question: 'query 8.1'),
      ]
   ),
];
 
  List<FAQCategory> filtered = [];
  for(FAQCategory parent in categories) {
        final temp = parent.items.where((child) => child.question.contains("query"));
        filtered.add(parent.copyWith(items: temp.toList()));
  }

  //result
  filtered.map((item)=> print(item)).toList();
}

class FAQCategory {
  late int id;
  late String title;
  late List<FAQItem> items;

  FAQCategory({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.items,
  });
  
  FAQCategory copyWith({int? id, String? title, List<FAQItem>? items}) => FAQCategory(
        id: id ?? this.id,
        title: title ?? this.title,
        items: items ?? this.items,
      );
  
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'id: $id, title: $title, items: ${items.map((e)=>e.question).toList()}';
  }
}

class FAQItem {
  late int id;
  late String question;
  late String answer;

  FAQItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.question,
    required this.answer,
  });
  
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'id: $id, question: $question, answer: $answer';
  }
}
```

Comment: I fail to see how this solves the question.

Comment: If you look for help, give more information please.

Comment: If you look for providing help please read the question fully. The entire information needed is stated in there.

Comment: I think you should have more respect to people who want help you. I added full code example.

Comment: I don't want to be rude. It's just that your answer does little to nothing for answering the question at hand. Please read again: "Now I want to filter a List<FAQCategory> based on query string but with respect to the fields title, question and answer. If one of the two fields in FAQItem match it should include the item, if title matches it should include the whole category."